# segfault in basic C mkstemp code

Tags: c, linux, gcc, posix

It seems that I'm completely misusing `mkstemp`. However I use it, I always get a segfault. I compiled the most basic program below with `gcc -ggdb -Wall -Werror main.c` and ran it with `./a.out`

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    mkstemp("XXXXXX");
    return 0;
}
```

This always returns the returncode 139 and it prints `[1]   23532 segmentation fault  ./a.out` on the terminal. (`23532` always changes because it's the pid).

I tried:

- switching the flags of `gcc` (none at all, a lot of combinations of the previous flags, `-Wextra` and `-O0`)
- Changing the code by saving the resulting filedescriptor in a `int`, sleeping 5 seconds and closing the filedescriptor again. But I don't even reach the start of the sleep...

And now I'm out of ideas...

Comment: the posted code, besides having an invalid parameter to `mkstemp()` to also be checking (!=NULL)) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the man page:

> The last six characters of `template` must be `"XXXXXX"` and these are
>          replaced with a string that makes the filename unique.  Since it will
>          be modified, `template` must not be a string constant, but should be
>          declared as a character array.

So you need to declare a character array:

```
char filename[] = "fileXXXXXX";
mkstemp(filename);
```